# Node.js require local file throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my project's filesystem.

```
root
index.js
package.json
...etc
commamds
- ping.js
- eval.js
- ...etc
```

This is a normal discord.js bot.
But when I try reloading the commands, I use the following code:

```js
...etc
let pull = require(`./${file}`);
// file is command files from fs.readdirSync() and it can be 'ping.js', 'eval.js', ...
...etc
```

But it throws a referenceerror that the module can't be found. But when I try fs.readFile(), it works. What's the problem?

Comment: Please replace `${file}` with an example of a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` defaults to the current working directory if there is no path or if there's a relative path on the filename.

`require()` has a completely separate set of rules for where it looks for files.  For example, a filename with no path at all looks in the `node_modules` directory and in the global module location(s).  A filename starting with `./` looks in the current module's home directory.  And so on...  It's a different set of rules than `fs.readFile()`.

Since you don't show us what `file` actually is, it's hard to know precisely, but perhaps you need to combine the filename with the appropriate path so you are giving `require()` a full path name and it will go exactly there, not use the normal rules for where `require()` looks when given only a plain filename.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the code as you said and it works!